# Bug in overlay of suggested edit

Tags: bug, design

When we try to take action on a suggested edit from the post itself, (from the Edit(1) in bottom), If the suggested edit is too large, the Overlay with the Opacity is appeared as broken

Sample image

**To a certain length**

[image]

**After scrolling some more**
[image]

**From that point**
[image]
In this third image, you can see that the overlay is ended at top and the normal page is shown at the bottom.

Comment: Repro'd on Graphic Design (manually editing the text in the dialog itself, rather than posting an actual long edit... [which got me edit banned when I tried](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293022/307988))

Comment: This edit is a person copied a code from codepen to the question. I found on chrome and I think it will be repro'd on all. @Cai