# Edit suspension message for anonymous users links to a non-existent edit history

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, 404-not-found, anonymous, edit-ban

I just got insta-suspended from suggesting edits whilst not logged in<sup>*</sup> and got a message saying:

> **You are currently suspended from suggesting edits**. You will be able to suggest edits again in 7 days. In the meantime, read about how [suggested edits are reviewed](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits) and visit [your edit history](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/0/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

The link, which is...

> `https://$site/users/0/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions`

...leads to a 404 page (and as far as I know there's no way for anonymous users to see their edit history?).

[image: You are currently suspended from suggesting edits.]

<sup>*</sup> I suggested two edits anonymously (in another browser, whilst not logged in). The first was a genuine edit to my own answer, which I instantly accepted (in the browser in which I *was* logged in); interestingly, the "system" [marked it as possible spam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLMSU.png). The second was a long edit of nonsense ([Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) to be precise), which on submitting sent me directly back to the post and silently disregarded the edit. On trying to submit another edit I got the message above.

Comment: Are anonymous users ever going to actually see that message?  I don't see a point in making the link work for anonymous users if anonymous users aren't going to be shown the link.

Comment: I just saw it as an anonymous user... Though that was clear from the screenshot?

Comment: As MSE's most prolific anonymous editor, I can confirm that anonymous users can definitely see it, and I agree this should be fixed.

Comment: One more thing to add to the mix: when an edit is submitted that trips the filter, all prior edits from the same IP address get the "possible spam" markup added to them, even retroactively to ones that were already handled.